# Does Hbase store data in Hexadecimal format?

Tags: hbase

I am newbie to Hbase dbms.
While trying command line shell of hbase , i found that i can read rowkey , col family and col qualifier as they were printed out in String but the value was printed in Hexadecimal format ( or something of that sort).
Whats the exact concept behind this ?

```
hbase(main):045:0* scan 'testtable'
ROW                                    COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                     
 19992                                 column=info:ismember, timestamp=1366957536788, value=\x00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No..Hbase stores everything as an "array of bytes". By doing so, it allows us to store any kind of data without much fuss. For example, imagine you have to store a product related data into your hbase table, say ID, make, country, price etc. To store each of these parameters you would have to take care of the individual datatypes of each of these parameters in advance which will definitely add some overhead. And unlike RDBMSs, hbase doesn't ask for all this at the time of table creation. So, even if datatypes of these parameters change tomorrow or you decide to add some parameters(with some new datatype), all you have to do is wrap the value in Bytes.ToBytes() and push it into your table. All this makes insertions faster.

Also, sometimes storing a value in a serialized byte[] form saves a few bytes as compared to storing the same values in their native format. And this minor saving becomes quite significant when you deal with BigData.

So, the concept behind this is that Hbase stores everthing as a byte[] to make things faster and to make storage more efficient, keeping the overhead of internal data structures to a minimum.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Ok..Thanks for the answer , but still this leaves me with my original question .. how to interpret byte arrays from hbase shell.From Java API , i can retrieve the data and see if its properly stored as expected or not .. but what about command line ? Its all hexadecimal characters in o/p.Please help here.

Comment: Which version are you using?You might find  this JIRA helpful : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6592..

Comment: I am using 0.94.6.1 version.

Comment: Tariq .. Could you please help here ? JIRA link is different then my question.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response Vimal. Was stuck with something important. Do you need something like this : http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/28346